# Stage becomes null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a game with AS3 in Flash Professional CS5.5.

In this game I have an "again" button, so that the player can reset the level and start from new.
My problem now is:

After the clicked "again" the stage becomes null.

All I do in the "ResetLevel" method is, that I set the x and y positions of some elements back to 0, remove some items from the movieclip, but I don't remove ALL items from the display list. So the background, the hud, the plane isn't removed from the movieclip. Here a sketch of my displaylist. The removeable items are sometimes zero, sometimes they are 30 or more items (depends on playtime, and so on)

```
Displaylist:

stage
|-- Game movieclip
    |--LevelBackground
    |--Removeable item 
    |--Removeable item
    |--Removeable item
    |--Plane
    |--HUD
```

But after removing the "removeable items" and setting the position coordinates of levelbackground and plane the stage is null.

Maybe someone can help me to point me to a solution for this problem.

**EDIT:**

The "ResetLevel"-method will be called inside the "game movieclip" and the stage will be accessed from the "game movieclip", too. So I don't remove the "game movieclip" from the displaylist when I reset the level. I only remove some elements, that the game movieclip contains from the movieclip.

Here some pseudocode from the "game movieclip class" (GameMC):

```
public class GameMC extends Sprite {

    //Some properties here

    public function GameMC() {
        //Some code here

        //--Events--
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init, false, 0, true);
        this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, Removed, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function Init(e:Event) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init);
        //Some Code here
    }

    private function ResetLevel() {
        //Some Code here, too
        if(removeItemArray.length > 0) {
            for(i = 0; i < removeItemArray.length; i++) {
                currentRemoveableItem = removeItemArray[i];
                this.removeChild(currentRemoveableItem );
                removeItemArray.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        level.x = 0;
        level.y = 0;

        trace(stage); //Will output null
    }
}
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#stage)->"`If a display object is not added to the display list, its stage property is set to null.`"

Comment: I know, but I don't remove the "Game movieclip" from my display list, and inside this movieclip I try to access the stage.stageWidth. Inside the "Game movieclip" I work with "ADDED_TO_STAGE" and "REMOVED_FROM_STAGE".

Comment: Is the GameMC by any chance attached to a library item you placed on the stage?  If so, then it will automatically be removed from the stage if your timeline jumps to a frame where it doesn't appear.

Comment: No, it's not. And I made a mistake in my code above, it's not extended MovieClip, it's extended Sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I used to store the stage into a property and access this:

```
public class GameMC extends Sprite { 

    //Some properties here
    private var stagevar:Stage;

    public function GameMC() { 
        //Some code here 

        //--Events-- 
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init, false, 0, true); 
        this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, Removed, false, 0, true); 
    } 

    private function Init(e:Event) { 
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init); 
        this.stagevar = stage;
        //Some Code here 
    } 

    private function ResetLevel() { 
        //Some Code here, too 
        if(removeItemArray.length > 0) { 
            for(i = 0; i < removeItemArray.length; i++) { 
                currentRemoveableItem = removeItemArray[i]; 
                this.removeChild(currentRemoveableItem ); 
                removeItemArray.splice(i, 1); 
            } 
        } 
        level.x = 0; 
        level.y = 0; 

        trace(stagevar); //Will output [Object Stage]
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When a DisplayObject is removed from the DisplayList, it does not hold any reference to the stage anymore. So, whatever you need to set/calculate, do it in a valid state. Event.ADDED, Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Event.REMOVED and Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE help to verify the DisplayObject's state is valid.

Comment: What you have written is correct.But it does not answer to "`Maybe someone can help me to point me to a solution for this problem?`" question.

Comment: Inside the "Game movieclip" I work with "ADDED_TO_STAGE" and "REMOVED_FROM_STAGE" and I don't remove the "game movieclip" from my stage/displaylist/whatever and inside this movieclip I try to access the stage.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way would be setting a flag, if the DisplayObject is on stage or not.

Comment: Edited my question with some pseudocode for better understanding.

Comment: You don't need a flag - just check if the `stage` reference is `null` - if it is, the object is not in the display list.